# OSRM Extract Silently Fails

Tags: osrm

I'm trying to setup a OSRM backend server using Docker. The host machine is a MacBook Pro with 32GB RAM running OS 10.14 (Mojave).

Having downloaded the england-latest.osm.pbf file I've tried to start the process with the following command.

```
docker run -t -v $(pwd):/data osrm/osrm-backend osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/england-latest.osm.pbf
```

The output is as follows:

```
[info] Parsed 0 location-dependent features with 0 GeoJSON polygons
[info] Using script /opt/car.lua
[info] Input file: england-latest.osm.pbf
[info] Profile: car.lua
[info] Threads: 6
[info] Parsing in progress..
[info] input file generated by osmium/1.8.0
[info] timestamp: 2018-11-02T21:15:02Z
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Found 3 turn restriction tags:
[info]   motorcar
[info]   motor_vehicle
[info]   vehicle
[info] Parse relations ...
[info] Parse ways and nodes ...
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
[info] Using profile api version 4
```

At this point the process silently fails and doesn't write any of the files you'd expect. If I use the greater-london-latest.osm.pbf file then everything works fine so I'm guessing it's some sort of memory constraint. How do I go about identifying the problem and fixing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After running into the same issue on my Mac, I solved it by increasing the memory available to Docker. Look for the whale icon on the menubar, click then select Preferences > Advanced. Change the slider to a higher amount, press Apply & Restart, then try running again.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/#memory

I could run within the 2GB default limit with a 415MB file (Canada > British Columbia) but nothing larger. Given the England file is 422MB, you can probably increase to 4GB and have it work. (Trying to run for all of Canada, a 2.4GB file, needed >8GB of RAM.)

Comment: Thanks Pat. Makes sense